# How to reference library files from a repositoryB during the build of src in repository A ?

Tags: linux, git, maven, tfs, cmake

There are two different repositories A and B in my TFS. On building sources in the repository A using cmake, I have to get some library files from repository B. I have to build the same source in the repository A on both a linux machine and a windows machine. For the Linux one I am getting the library files from the repository B using maven. please see the code below:

```
stage('dependencies')
    {
            sh '''
            # get the project dependencies
            mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -f ./pom.xml

            # unpack the dependency RPMs to a local install dir
            for rpm in ./target/dependency/*.rpm; do
                rpm2cpio $rpm | cpio -idmv
            done
        '''
    }
```

This was done by another person working before me. So can someone explain to me what exactly this script does here and also how can i do the same for a windows machine. Do i create a bat script somehow and use maven for that too? I dont understand how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: sh runs a shell script, you need to convert the script from bash to bat for a windows machine, it's only doing maven commands so you need to replicate that command on a windows machine.

Comment: Which version control are you using in TFS? According to the tag, are you using GIT as your source control？

Comment: Yes I am using GIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a built-in solution with TFS build for now. You could vote up and monitor below related uservoice:

> **Allow TFS build to depend on multiple repositories** https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/11592954-allow-tfs-build-to-depend-on-multiple-repositories

However, you could use some workarounds. The easiest and manageable way is using Nuget package. Creating your nuget package in the server and [restore the package](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer)  during build pipeline. More details with Package Management in Team  TFS, you could refer this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/overview).